# Disable decoding of xml text content

Tags: java, xml, parsing

Is it possible to disable decoding xml text content when parsing an xml file using Java?
For example so `&quot;` is returned as is instead of being converted to a quote

Effectively want the text content treated as if it was wrapped in a CDATA block

Comment: You mentioned CDATA which does exactly what you want. For what reason don't you want use it?

Comment: The xml files already exist (without CDATA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[kXML 2](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/kxml2/) has the Options **[expand-entity-ref](http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#expand-entity-ref)** and **[xml-roundtrip](http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#xml-roundtrip)** that would allow to do this.

Answer (score 2):

What would be the harm of letting the parser replace the entity and then re-replacing later?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that would be highly questionable to do. After all, these two xml snippets **are exactly the same thing** from the XML perspective, if &quot; has been defined as meaning ":

```
<a>&quot;<b></b></a>
```

and

```
<a>"<b/></a>
```

And if &quot; has not been defined, the first input is not valid anyway. So, from the viewpoint of *meaning,* you are actually asking to *get* a conversion, not to avoid one.

Any parser that sees a difference between these inputs is **not** behaving as an XML parser. (And a program relying on seeing a difference is not really dealing with XML, it tries to deal with text files with some imposed structure.)

I'm not sure what the output should be in any case. Would you want your Java code to see a text node which has a value of `"&quot;"`? But the xml input for that would have been `&amp;quot;`, and that's also what xml output of such a text node would be.